# Change the input type of edittext for a certain portion of the string

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

I have a input field i want it to take input like a password until string length is 8 and after that the input type should change to text, that means if the input field has 12 characters starting 8 characters should be asterisk and other 4 should be text.
The method i am using now changes the type of whole edittext but i don't want that.

```
etEmail.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            email = etEmail.getText().toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            email = etEmail.getText().toString();
            if(email.length() > 8){
                etEmail.setTransformationMethod(null);
                etEmail.setSelection(etEmail.length());

            }

        }
    });
```

If this is the string: 123456789012
The input field should show it like that: ********9012

Comment: Use TextWatcher(Link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html ) and in `onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)` you can get the position and achieve your desired case, try this and then post if you find any problem

Comment: actually i am using text watcher, the upper methods which i am using are placed inside text watcher on textchange listener, but they are changing the input type for whole input field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to add cases for null exception and character length and add special cases according to your requirement however this is the basic implementation of your requested query**

```
etUsername.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (charSequence.length() != 0 && charSequence.length() <= 8  && i < charSequence.length() ) {

                    updatedString = etUsername.getText().toString().substring(0,charSequence.length()).replaceAll("[0-9]", "*");
                    etUsername.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                    etUsername.setText(updatedString);
                    etUsername.setSelection(charSequence.length());
                    etUsername.addTextChangedListener(this);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
               /* if (etUsername.length() != 0 ){
                    updatedString = etUsername.getText().toString().substring(0,(etUsername.length() > 8 ? 8 : etUsername.length())).replaceAll("[0-9]", "*");
                    etUsername.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                    etUsername.setText(updatedString);
                    etUsername.setSelection(etUsername.length());
                    etUsername.addTextChangedListener(this);
                }*/

            }
        });
```

**The checks I have added to avoid null pointer exception**

```
updatedString = etUsername.getText().toString().substring(0,charSequence.length()).replaceAll("[0-9]", "*");
```

> In **replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)** you can provide any regex , moreover you can optimize it more for performance I am just providing you the basic idea.

Comment: Throwing uncaught exception at etUsername.setSelection(charSequence.length());

Comment: @ManojKumar `etUsername.setSelection(charSequence.length());` this line is just adjusting the cursor nothing else, have you tried running code onTextChanged, donot run the code of afterTextChanged I have commented out that code

Comment: yes i have tried doing it without that line, it isn't replacing the numbers, numbers are not even showing in the input field.

Comment: @ManojKumar Try cleaning and rebuilding the project and add `etUsername.setSelection(charSequence.length());` It will work if it's not then let me know

Comment: Thanks for your help.. I had upwoted your answer but my reputation is below 15 that's why it is not reflecting..

Answer (score 1):

Its not not possible both visible password and password  in single EditText.

if you want change whole edittext (visible password or password) change by using **TextWatcher onTextChanged** method based on char count (when its reach 8).

Note : editText may be password or Visible .cant combine both the property in single EditText.But we can different the character above 8 by using custom way

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);


private final TextWatcher  textWatcher= new TextWatcher() {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
     // if(s.length()==8)
     // setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);

      //or replace some text above char 8
       if(s.length()>=8)
       {
       s = s.replace(s.substring(8,s.length()), "replace some special character");
       editText.setText(s);
       }


    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
};
```

Comment: Is there any way to change the input character?

Comment: I am doing exactly like that but it is not the solution which i am looking for. @ sasikumar

Comment: this will not work on first charater it will indexoutofboundexception

Comment: use s.replace(s.substring(8,s.length()-1)

Comment: use if(s.length()>=8)

Comment: even if it work with this condition then it would replace the character after length is greater then 8, and i don't want that..

Answer (score 0):

Use below code I have tried and getting the expected result as you suggested.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText et;
TextWatcher myTextWatcher;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    et = findViewById(R.id.et);

    myTextWatcher = new MyTextListener();

    et.addTextChangedListener(myTextWatcher);
}

private void updateEditText(String text) {
    if (text.length() < 9) {
        String converted="";
        for (int a=0; a< text.length(); a++) {
            converted = converted + "*";
        }
        et.removeTextChangedListener(myTextWatcher);
        et.setText(converted);
        et.setSelection(text.length());
        et.addTextChangedListener(myTextWatcher);
    }
}

private class MyTextListener implements TextWatcher {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        updateEditText(charSequence.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
}
```

}

And for xml use below xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Hope that solves your problem. If you found any problem must share with me.

Comment: that means you are missing something. I have checked above code and that is working according to your need

Comment: i don't think i have missed anything, i did exactly same as yours and i checked it twice..

Answer (score 0):

Try this I did it for you and checked it... it works fine..

```
etEmail.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
   String originalText = "";
   String newCharacter = "";
   String starCharacter = "";
   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
   }
   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
      if(s.length()>0) {
         if(originalText.length()<s.length()) {
             newCharacter = s.toString().substring(s.toString().length() - 1);
         }else{
             newCharacter = "";
         }
       }else{
          newCharacter = "";
          originalText = "";
       }
   }
   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
       if(s.length()>0){
           //Lock the listener
           etEmail.removeTextChangedListener(this);
           if(s.length()<=8){
               starCharacter = "";
               for (int i = 0; i <s.length() ; i++) {
                   starCharacter += "*";
               }
               etEmail.setText(starCharacter);
               originalText+=newCharacter;
           }else{
               if(!newCharacter.equals("")) {
                   originalText += newCharacter;
               }else{
                   originalText = originalText.substring(0, originalText.length()-1);
               }

                starCharacter = "********";
                etEmail.setText(starCharacter + originalText.substring(8));
            }
                etEmail.setSelection(etEmail.getText().toString().length());
                //Give back the listener
                etEmail.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }else{
                originalText = "";
            }
      }
});
```

Best of luck..